# Finding Coefficients of a Pairing Friendly Elliptic Curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

Assuming that I know the size of the base field ($q$), size of the prime order subgroup ($r$), and embedding degree of the curve ($k$) of a pairing friendly elliptic curve ($E$), I would like to instantiate a curve in both Weierstrass and Edwards form.

How do I find $A, B$ (also $c, d$) when I know the $q, r,$ and $k$?

$E: y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$

$E: u^2 + v^2 = c^2 (1 + d \cdot u^2  v^2)$

where $r$ divides $\#E(\mathcal{F}_q)$ and $k$ is the smallest integer such that $r$ divides $q^k - 1$.

Comment: $q$ was obtained using Cock-Pinch method (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.0971.pdf). Is Complex Multiplication (https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/ep/cm.html) the only way to generate the curves?